# nullpointer exception at a search method in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I tracked down the bugger, but I am no closer to understanding what is wrong. Here is what the compiler says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   BasicFile.Search(BasicFile.java:215) at
>   TestFile.main(TestFile.java:42)

Line 215 is the one that starts with while, first one.

```
String Search(String key) throws IOException {

    int lines = 0;
    String line = "";
    String foundAt = "";
    BufferedReader BF = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

    try {
        while ((line = BF.readLine().toLowerCase()) != null) {
            lines++;
            //create tokenizer words with what is in line
            StringTokenizer words = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while(words.hasMoreTokens()) { //while words has tokens left
                //go to next token and compare to key
                if (words.nextToken().equals(key.toLowerCase())) 
                    foundAt = foundAt + "\n" + lines + ":" + line;
                //do nothing continue loop                     
            }
        }
        BF.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return foundAt;
}
```

Comment: You put `!=` to check if the value returned is not `null`. But you're using the value returned by invoking a method on it...

Comment: Why do you have `!= null`? What could be `null`? The answer is the value returned by `BF.readLine()`. If that can be `null`, why are you invoking a method on it?

Comment: I was trying to be all tricky and doing it all on one line... I should have been more careful. My shame to live with.

Comment: Till the end of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your buffer reader runs out of lines it returns `null`. You are trying to call `toLowerCase` method on null which ends up throwing the null pointer exception.

Refactor your code in a way that it doesn't require you to execute `toLowerCase` before ensuring the line is non-null.

For example:

```
String next;

while ((next = BF.readLine()) != null) {
   String line = next.toLowerCase();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: ah! I see, now the tricky part will be finding a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = BF.readLine().toLowerCase()) != null)
```

What happens if BF.readline() returns null?

Comment: null pointer exception... I just learned that 10 seconds ago.

Comment: @user3236502: Indeed, you are trying to call a method on null. Test for null *before* doing that.

Comment: @user3236502: That is why i phrased the answer as a question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

remove `.toLowerCase()` from the test

Comment: But I must make it lowercase otherwise it may not return a value like Cat will be not found if I am looking for cat.

Comment: jsalonen replied to you. I cannot explain it better than him.

Answer (score 0):

Please, stop it, your code is giving me cancer! There are a number of stylistic errors in the code that you need to fix.

- First off **in java, method names always begin with a lowercase letter**. You are programming in Java, not C#, so you need to use the Java naming conventions. That means your method should be called `search`, not `Search`.
- The same goes for variable names. What is `BF` supposed to mean, anyway? Replace it with `in`, please.
- Next up, unless this method is in an object that itself *represents that particular file*, the global variable `f` should be passed as a parameter instead.
- `BufferedReader` is `AutoCloseable`, so you should use a try-with-resources to deal with closing it.
- You need to add a javadoc comment to it, documenting its parameters with `@param`, its return with `@return`, and exactly why it might need to throw an `IOException` with `@exception`.

Here is a mostly-fixed version of your code:

```
/**
 * Needs Javadoc
 */
String search(String key, File f) throws IOException {

    int lines = 0
    String line = "";
    String foundAt = "";

    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)) {

        while ((line = in.readLine().toLowerCase()) != null) { //the line in question

            lines++;
            StringTokenizer words = new StringTokenizer(line);

            while(words.hasMoreTokens()) 
                if (words.nextToken().equals(key.toLowerCase()))
                    foundAt = foundAt + "\n" + lines + ":" + line;                     
        }

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){}

    return foundAt;
}
```

Now, the problem here is that `in.readline()` returns a `null` sometimes. Calling a method on a `null` is always a `NullPointerException`. Therefore you get a `NullPointerException` when you attempt to call that `null`'s missing `toLowerCase()` method.

You need to convert it `toLowerCase` *after* you ensure it is non-null.

Comment: I just do things the way the professor asks, he is the one that set up the global variable. BF and Search.

Comment: @user3236502 don't let yourself be cheated out of proper education! You should _demand_ that to be taught real java.

Comment: @user3236502 If I were teaching a programming class, I would take off major points from any code that didn't use proper style, even if the bad style was from bad template code given to students.